# Select by subcollection count in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have an mongo object like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fa291baf5de89b89cb03f4e"),
    "examples" : [
        "!@3123123123", "23423fd34", "23423we4234"
    ]
}
```

I need to select all objects that have >= 3 examples.
What is the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do that. If your collection is not huge, only a couple thousand entries, then you can do it like this:

```
User.all.select {|user| !user['examples'].nil? and user['examples'].count >= 3}
```

That loads ALL entries from the collection into memory and does the selection with a Ruby native feature. You should not do this if you have 10 million entries in the collection.

Since MongoDB 2.2+ you can do this:

```
User.collection.find({'examples.2' => {'$exists' => true}})
```

That will return all users which have at least 3 elements in the 'example' subcollection. The counting starts with 0, the position of the element in the subcollection. 
We use this feature at [VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com) to identify users who don't follow anything.

Comment: By the way. The code snippet I posted is from Ruby. You might change the syntax a bit for other languages. But in general it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Maintain a dedicated counter variable as part of the document and use this one for performing a related query.

Comment: That's what I don't wont to do :-)

Comment: Benjamin, it's the best way though. Map reduce is overkill for this.

Comment: +1 Using a counter is the correct solution for MongoDB. As Derick stated you could use map/reduce, but it's very slow and limited to collections of a maximum of 20,000 objects.

Comment: @theTRON any references to 20000 objects limit?

Comment: Alas, I cannot find a doc reference to this now. I know that I have hit this limit in the past when I was benchmarking map/reduce on collections greater than 100,000 objects. However I believe these limits have been resolved by the recent MongoDB aggregation framework.